# Persistent CORS error with React/Node running in docker-compose on Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

I am trying to get a streaming service running from a modified version of an open source repo https://github.com/nabendu82/streams.

I have a frontend client in React, a RTMP server for the stream, and a backend API.  I have got a docker compose file to host them all together.  If I run `docker-compose up` on my local computer, everything works perfectly. I can visit http://localhost:3000/matches/view and see two stream windows that aren't loaded, until I open up the streaming software OBS, `Settings -> Stream -> Server: rtmp://localhost/live, Stream Key: 7.`  Then the right stream window will start.

To host this repo on the internet, I've created a basic EC2 instance on AWS (http://13.54.200.18:3000/matches/view).  I installed `docker-compose` and I've copied all the repo files up to it.

However, when running on the AWS box the stream does not load, and the console error is always the spectacularly unhelpful:

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://server:3002/streams/6. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).`

So for some reason CORS is preventing the React frontend from reading the server backend while it is hosted on AWS.

Here is the catch.  I can actually get the streaming on the AWS hosted site to work, but only by running `docker-compose up` on my LOCAL computer at the same time.  For some unknown reason, the AWS hosted version is able to pick up on the backend server running on my local machine (rather than the one running alongside it in docker-compose on AWS) and connect that way.  I can even stream to the website via OBS at `rtmp://13.54.200.18/live` and everything works.  But it only works on exactly my local computer running the docker-compose infrastructure (and only if I use calls to 'localhost' instead of the docker-compose service 'server'), if anyone else tries to see the stream on the live site they will just get Loading... perpetually and the CORS error.

Why is the AWS hosted code not looking at its own docker-compose file and its own server:3002 service?  For the rest of the world, and for me if I'm not running a local server, it throws a CORS error. For just my local computer, and only if I'm running a local server and making requests to 'localhost:3002', it works perfectly.

If I ssh on to the AWS image, then `docker-compose run client curl localhost:3002/streams` will fail, but `docker-compose run client curl server:3002/streams` will give me back the correct JSON data.  From everything I understand about docker compose, my services should be able to access each other and it appears they can, everything works great locally, and the services can talk to each other on the AWS box too, but just somehow this CORS error appears out of nowhere only on the AWS hosted version.

I've tried everything under the sun I can think of. I was originally using `json-server`, but I thought that might be the issue (as it has to specifically bind to -H 0.0.0.0), so I wrote my own Express server using the cors package to replace it and there has been no change.  I've tried every configuration of docker-compose variables I can imagine.  As far as I can understand I've done everything right, but somehow the AWS box wants to talk to my own computer's localhost aka "server service" aka 0.0.0.0 instead of its own.  What is going on?

Repository here: https://github.com/JeremyEllingham/streams

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out how to get it working, by just posting direct to the Linux box IP address in production instead of trying to get it working with "localhost" or the docker service names.  Kind of disappointed that docker-compose doesn't seem to work quite like I thought it did, but it's totally functional to just conditionally alter the base URL.

See also this answer: [React app (in a docker container) cannot access API (in a docker container) on AWS EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50139880/react-app-in-a-docker-container-cannot-access-api-in-a-docker-container-on-a?rq=1)